# How to remove Branding WHMCS Ver 8.1 "Powered by WHMcomplete solutions"

Tags: php, jquery, css, templates, whmcs

I am a newbie and this is the first time ever I am asking a question in this community.

One of my friends just recently update his WHMCS to the latest version and suddenly he got a branding line before the footer area. In the previous version, he was able to remove that line by editing the footer.tpl file but in this version, he couldn't find it because now it's written in tags. (p and a)

I found one jquery code mentioned below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("p a").each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr("href")=="http://www.whmcs.com/" ) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

But I don't know either it's fine or where to put this one.

Please guide and help how to remove it, as now in the client area it is visible to everyone now.

Comment: if above code works, it could reduce like 
```$(document).ready(function () {
  $('p a[href="http://www.whmcs.com/"]').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)... This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("[href*='whmcs.com']").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  
});
```

So you now target the elements by the `href` value... Whatever the DOM structure.

If the `href` contains `whmcs.com` (the `*=` operator), the parent of that element will be removed.

Comment: Thanks @louys, but where to put this code? In header.tpl or footer.tpl?

Comment: At the end of the `<head>` would be a good place.

Comment: This worked for me in include/head.tpl in v8.

Answer (score 2):

In version 8.3 go to your template, I am using the "twentyone" template. Access your footer.tpl and paste this on line 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("p:contains('Powered by')").remove();$('#page');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to remove WHMCS branding.

```
<script>
    if($("p:contains('Powered by')").length){
        $("p:contains('Powered by')").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code in custom.css in your template

```
#main-body .primary-content p:last-child{
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested.

Am using the SwiftModders theme and found it in the following file

```
\templates\swiftmodders\js\swiftmodders.min.js
```

Used Notepad++ and searched "Powered by" and deleted that section.

Issue resolved ^^

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29791131)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove WHMCS branding.

1. In the admin area, you can edit the footer.tpl file to remove the link to whmcs.com from the main admin area.

From the login page, you can edit *admindir*/templates/login.tpl to remove the link

2. Second goto your Footer file and paste this script.

```js
<script>if ($(“p:contains(‘Powered by’)”).length) {$(“p:contains(‘Powered by’)”).hide();}</script>
```

Comment: The client area script didn't work for me even after I corrected your syntax errors.  Wrong html quote types.  Still doesn't work in code snippet so there is some other error.